# Building acoustic model in speech recognition

Tags: sphinx, speech-recognition, decoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I missing the an4-1-1.match file in this speech recognition code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739675/why-am-i-missing-the-an4-1-1-match-file-in-this-speech-recognition-code)

I'm doing speech recognition and using Ubuntu as my OS
I am having problems in decoding.
I have followed all the instructions [here](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/sphinx/tutorial.html#pocketsphinx).
I have downloaded Sphinxbase, Sphinx3, an4, and Sphinxtrain and 'configure -> make' each folder.
But when I get to the decoding part.
And when I typed 'perl scripts_pl/decode/slave.pl'
I have these error.

```
MODULE: DECODE Decoding using models previously trained
        Decoding 130 segments starting at 0 (part 1 of 1) 
Could not find executable for /home/go/Documents/tutorial/an4/bin/sphinx3_decode at /home/go/Documents/tutorial/an4/scripts_pl/decode/../lib/SphinxTrain/Util.pm line 299.
        Aligning results to find error rate
Can't open /home/go/Documents/tutorial/an4/result/an4-1-1.match
word_align.pl failed with error code 65280 at scripts_pl/decode/slave.pl line 173.
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: yes. I want to ask the same question too, "What might be the problem?" Without looking into your `Util.pm` , `an4-1-1.match` and `word_align.pl` , how can we know what is the problem ?

Comment: Here are the links.
But I don't know why I am missing an4-1-1.match

word_align.pl --> http://www.mediafire.com/?xv9ygyx83t19g6t
Util.pm --> http://www.mediafire.com/?kb7izn27gwbegqm

I would appreciate of any help.

Thanks

Comment: you can post the related codes here. SO is code-friendly.

Comment: I made a thread. Please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739675/need-help-in-speech-recognition I would appreciate of any help. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a good idea to post duplicate question on the same subject. You can just edit the original question instead