# Why am I missing the an4-1-1.match file in this speech recognition code?

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I'm having problems in the decoding part of speech recognition. I followed the steps [here](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/sphinx/tutorial.html). When I type: `perl scripts_pl/decode/slave.pl`, I get these errors:

> MODULE: DECODE Decoding using models previously trained
>           Decoding 130 segments starting at 0 (part 1 of 1)  Could not find executable for /home/go/Documents/tutorial/an4/bin/sphinx3_decode
>   at
>   /home/go/Documents/tutorial/an4/scripts_pl/decode/../lib/SphinxTrain/Util.pm
>   line 299.
>           Aligning results to find error rate Can't open /home/go/Documents/tutorial/an4/result/an4-1-1.match word_align.pl
>   failed with error code 65280 at scripts_pl/decode/slave.pl line 173.

Here is `word_align.pl` line 179

```
#sub initialize {
    my ($ref_words, $hyp_words, $align_matrix, $backtrace_matrix) = @_;

    # All initial costs along the j axis are insertions
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= @$hyp_words; ++$j) {
    $$align_matrix[0][$j] = $j;
    }
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= @$hyp_words; ++$j) {
    $$backtrace_matrix[0][$j] = INS;
    }
    # All initial costs along the i axis are deletions
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= @$ref_words; ++$i) {
    $$align_matrix[$i][0] = $i;
    }
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= @$ref_words; ++$i) {
    $$backtrace_matrix[$i][0] = DEL;
    }
#}
```

and `Util.pm` line 299

> die "Could not find executable for $cmd" unless -e $cmd;

Why am I missing the `an4-1-1.match file`?

Answer (score 0):

> I followed the steps here http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/sphinx/tutorial.html

This tutorial is outdated. A recent one is http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

> Could not find executable for
>   /home/go/Documents/tutorial/an4/bin/sphinx3_decode

This is a reason of the problem. You need to copy the executable to the specified location. Then run decoding again.